# rhandsontable new data addition: Error in seq.default: argument 'length.out' must be of length 1

Tags: r, postgresql, sqlite, shiny, rhandsontable

I ran into a problem using rhandsontable on my shinyapp after i was advised to migrate from SQLite to Postgres for scaling purposes and multi-transaction management. I thought the process at least on the shiny application layer would not be that different. The update, remove-row and all the other queries a user sents just work fine on Postgres. I am facing a problem when it comes to adding new data (rows), the below code works well when I have it integrated to SQLite but I get the following error when connected to PostgreSQL with a crush when attempting to save.

I saw multiple GitHub posts reported on this issue on rhandsontable package but doesn't seem like there's a definite answer except the requirement to update the package.

> Warning: Error in seq.default: argument 'length.out' must be of length 1
> 79: stop
> 78: seq.default
> 76: genRowHeaders
> 75: 
> 73: hot_to_r
> 72: observeEventHandler [modules/databases/Truck_Receipts_Database.R#50]
> 1: runApp

```
  Truck_Receipts_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(  
    sidebarLayout(
      absolutePanel(id = "controls", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
        draggable = TRUE, top = 250, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
        width = 230, height = "auto",
        h2(strong("Control Menu")),
        shinyalert("shinyalert2", FALSE,auto.close.after = 2),
        selectInput(ns("dataset"), "Blasting Database",  choices = c("blasting1")),   
        actionButton(ns("saveBtn"), "Save Changes",class = "btn-info"), 
        hr(),
        radioButtons(ns("filetype"), "File-type Selector",
         choices = c("csv")), 
        downloadButton(ns('downloadData'), 'Download Data', class = "btn-primary"),
        hr(),
        fileInput(inputId = ns("fileDrive"), 
                  label = "Upload Transactions Verification Documents",
                  accept = NULL)
        ), 
      mainPanel( 
        fluidRow(
          style='height:40vh',br(),br(),
          withSpinner(rHandsontableOutput(ns('tabletest') , height = "75vh" ))
          ),width = 12), 
      position = c("right")
      ) 
    )
}

Truck_Receipts <- function(input, output, session, pool) { 
  tableChoozer<-reactive({ input$dataset })   
  p1<-reactive({  
    results<-dbGetQuery(pool,paste('SELECT * FROM  ',tableChoozer()))
    return(results)
    })    
  data_base<-function(){dbGetQuery(pool,paste('select * from ',tableChoozer()))}
  observe({
    if (input$saveBtn == 0) 
    return()
    showshinyalert(session, "shinyalert2", paste("Database updated"),styleclass = "warning")
    }) 
  Mychanges<-reactive({ 
    observeEvent( 
      input$saveBtn,{  
        p1<-data_base()
        drops<-c("Comment" )
  
        if(any(is.na(hot_to_r(input$tabletest))[,!(names(hot_to_r(input$tabletest))%in%drops)]))
        {
          #make no changes #incomplete data entry
          as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$tabletest))
          #pop ups must be here
        
        }else{
          if((NROW(p1())!=NROW(hot_to_r(input$tabletest)))&&(!identical(p1,hot_to_r(input$tabletest)))){ 
            stackeddf<-rbind(hot_to_r(input$tabletest), p1)
            finaldf<-unique(stackeddf) 
            if((NROW(hot_to_r(input$tabletest))>NROW(p1()))&&(NROW(p1())<NROW(finaldf))&&(identical(finaldf,hot_to_r(input$tabletest))) 
            ){  

                  # new data entry 
#works well on SQLite
dbWriteTable(pool,tableChoozer(),finaldf,overwrite=T,append=F,row.names=F)


#I tried using insert by row to see if it will solve the problem but still does not work, the following commented out code works well outside of the application

         
          #    new_df<-setdiff(tableChoozer(),finaldf)
              #add the compare feature #hope it works
              
              #last_rows<-tail(blasting2, n = 2)
        #      x<-c()
        #      for (i in 1:NROW(new_df)){
        #        x[[i]]<-dput(as.character(paste(new_df[i,])))
        #      }  
        #      d<-gsub("\\]", ")", gsub("\\[", "(", jsonlite::toJSON(x))) 
        #      bb<-gsub("\"","\'", d)
        #      BB<-substring(bb, 2, nchar(bb)-1)  
              #paste("testing",BB,";")
              
         #      dbGetQuery(pool,paste("INSERT INTO blasting1(
        #       id, date, shift, time_in, time_out, reference_no, service_provider, product_code, blasted_quantity, comment)
        #       VALUES",BB,";")) 
              #dbGetQuery(pool,paste("INSERT INTO blasting1(
              #id, date, shift, time_in, time_out, reference_no, service_provider, product_code, blasted_quantity, comment)
                #VALUES hot_to_r(input$tabletest$select$rAll);"))
           
         
            }else if((NROW(hot_to_r(input$tabletest))>NROW(p1()))&&(NROW(p1())<NROW(finaldf))&&(!identical(finaldf,hot_to_r(input$tabletest))) ){
              #multiple users capturing
 
          dbWriteTable(pool,tableChoozer(),finaldf,overwrite=T,append=F,row.names=F)
         
            }
            else if((NROW(hot_to_r(input$tabletest))<NROW(p1()))&&(NROW(p1())==NROW(finaldf)) 
           ){
              #remove existing data 
             dbWriteTable(pool,tableChoozer(),hot_to_r(input$tabletest),overwrite=T,append=F,row.names=F)  
            } 
          }else{ 
            if((NROW(p1)==NROW(hot_to_r(input$tabletest)))&&
               (identical(p1,hot_to_r(input$tabletest))) 
            ){
              #make no changes  
              as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$tabletest)) 
            } 
            else if( 
              (NROW(p1())==NROW(hot_to_r(input$tabletest)))&&(!identical(p1(),hot_to_r(input$tabletest)))
            ){ 
              #replacing data
          dbWriteTable(pool,tableChoozer(),hot_to_r(input$tabletest),overwrite=T,append=F,row.names=F) 
            }
          }
        }
      },ignoreInit = T)   
    #inception dataframe pull
    if(TRUE){
      return(p1())}  
  })
  
  
  output$tabletest<-renderRHandsontable({  
    rhandsontable( Mychanges(),search = TRUE)%>%
      hot_cols(columnSorting = TRUE,highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE,manualColumnResize = T) %>%
      hot_cols(fixedColumnsLeft = 2) %>%
  #    hot_cell(1, 1, "")%>%
  #  hot_col(col = "Date", type = "date", dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD")%>% 
   #   hot_cols(fixedColumnsLeft = 2)%>%  hot_col(col = "Shift",  type = "autocomplete", source = c("A","B","C"),strict = FALSE)%>% 
    #  hot_col(col = "Shift",  type = "autocomplete", source = c("A","B","C"),strict = FALSE)%>% 
  #    hot_col(col = "Supplier details",  type = "autocomplete", source = c("FT000001 - Fertiliser raw","NT000001 - Nitrogen",
  #                                                                         "PH00001 - Phosphate","OTRW0000 - Other","PF00000 - Packaging material"),strict = FALSE)%>% 
  #    hot_col(col = "Bin code",  type = "autocomplete", source = c("1001 - Finished product","1002 - Raw materials","1003 - Packaging","1006 - Blend","1010 - Coal"),strict = FALSE)%>% 
  #    hot_col(col = "Pack size",  type = "autocomplete", source = c("2 kg","5 kg","10 kg","25 kg","37.50 kg","50 kg","1000 kg","1250 kg","1500 kg","Bulk","BG"),strict = FALSE)%>% 
  #    hot_col(col = "Product code",  type = "autocomplete", source =dput(as.character(paste(Product_codes()[[2]],Product_codes()[[1]],sep="-"))),strict = FALSE)%>% 
  #    hot_cols(renderer = "
  #             function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  #             Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments); 
  #             var isValid = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/; 
  #             if (value < 0) {td.style.background = 'pink';}  
  #                     if(col==2&& !isValid.test(value)) {td.style.background = 'pink';} 
  #            if(col==3&& !isValid.test(value)) {td.style.background = 'pink';}  
  #            if(col==1&&!['A','B','C'].includes(value)){td.style.background = 'pink';}
  #             }")%>%  
 
    hot_context_menu(
      customOpts = list(
        search = list(name = "Search",
          callback = htmlwidgets::JS(
            "function (key, options) {
              var srch = prompt('Search criteria'); 
              this.search.query(srch);
              this.render();
              }")))) %>%
    hot_cell(1, 3, "")
    }) 
  output$downloadData<-downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){paste("table.csv")},
    content = function(file){
      sep <- switch(input$filetype, "csv" = ",") 
      write.table(p1(), file, sep = sep, row.names = FALSE)}
      ) 
  observe({
    if (is.null(input$fileDrive)) return()
    file.copy(input$fileDrive$datapath, file.path(paste(getwd(),"/truck_receipts_v",sep = ""),input$fileDrive$name), overwrite = TRUE) #used for local testing
    # file.copy(input$fileDrive$datapath, file.path("/mnt/persistent/truck_receipts_v",input$fileDrive$name), overwrite = TRUE) #server side
  })
}
```

Comment: looks like the problem is with hot_to_r, works well when I have SQLite but doesn't work when I have Postgres

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked multiple times on the rhandsontable github page. I looked at the following to reproduce the error.

The following code reproduces the error:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

    ui <- function() {
        fluidRow(actionButton(inputId = "download", label = "Save"),
                 rHandsontableOutput("tab")
                 )
       # fluidRow()
    }
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
        output$tab <- renderRHandsontable({
            rhandsontable(mtcars)
            print  (mtcars)
            #output$tab <- renderRHandsontable({
              #   if (!is.null(input$tab)) {
              #    DF = hot_to_r(input$tab) 
              #  } else {
              #     DF = mtcars
             #  }
            #  rhandsontable(DF)
            #})
        })
        
        save <- observe({
            if(input$download == 0) return()
              saveRDS(hot_to_r(input$tab), file = "test.rds")
            print(hot_to_r(input$tab))
        })
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The following solved the issue as suggested by jrowen on one of the issues posts.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- function() {
    fluidRow(actionButton(inputId = "download", label = "Save"),
             rHandsontableOutput("tab")
             )
   # fluidRow()
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    #output$tab <- renderRHandsontable({
    #    rhandsontable(mtcars)
      #  print  (mtcars)
        output$tab <- renderRHandsontable({
             if (!is.null(input$tab)) {
              DF = hot_to_r(input$tab) 
            } else {
               DF = mtcars
           }
          rhandsontable(DF)
        #})
    })
    
    save <- observe({
        if(input$download == 0) return()
          saveRDS(hot_to_r(input$tab), file = "test.rds")
        print(hot_to_r(input$tab))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So in terms of the problem above, I just added the following then the crashing problem stopped.

```
  output$tabletest<-renderRHandsontable({  
  
      if (!is.null(input$tabletest)) {
        DF =  hot_to_r(input$tabletest)
      } else {
        DF =  Mychanges()
      }
     
    rhandsontable(DF  ,search = TRUE)%>%
      hot_cols(columnSorting = TRUE,highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE,manualColumnResize = T) %>%
      hot_cols(fixedColumnsLeft = 2) %>%
```